# solving Second Order Non-homogeneous Cauchy-Euler Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$2x^2y''-11xy'-7y=3x^7$

It has two real solutions : $7,-\frac{1}{2}$

I got the general solution for the homogeneous part: $y_g =c_1x^7+\frac{c_2}{\sqrt{x}}$

Now I want to get the particular solution for $y_g=3x^7$

Which method is best here? I used The "variation of parameters method" but I think I got stuck with the integral:

$W(x^7,x^{\frac{1}{2}})=...=-\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{15}{2}}-7x^{\frac{11}{2}}$

$y_p= -x^7\int\frac{x^{-\frac{1}{2}}3x^5}{-\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{15}{2}}-7x^{\frac{11}{2}}}dx+x^{-\frac{1}{2}}\int\frac{x^73x^5}{-\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{15}{2}}-7x^{\frac{11}{2}}}dx$

Am I doing this right?

Comment: You can use undertermined coefficients here. The particular solution has the form $y_p(x)= Ax^7\ln x$

Comment: @Dylan, Yup It works! That's even simpler.Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the ansatz $$y(x)=x^r$$ then you have to solve $$2r^2-13r-7=0$$ and you get
$$y(x)=\frac{C_1}{\sqrt{x}}+C_2x^7$$ a particular solution can be find by the method of variation of the constants. It is $$y_p=-\frac{2x^7}{75}+\frac{1}{5}x^7\log(x)$$
Let $$y_{b_1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}},y_{b_2}=x^7$$ then we get
$$W(x)=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}&x^7\\\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})&\frac{d}{dx}(x^7)\end{vmatrix}$$
And this is $$\frac{15}{2}x^{\frac{11}{2}}$$. Let $$f(x)=\frac{3}{2}x^5$$ then we obtain
$$v_1=-\int\frac{f(x)y_{b_2}}{W(x)}dx$$ and $$v_2=\frac{f(x)y_{b_1}(x)}{W(x)}dx$$
and we get
$$y_p(x)=v_1y_{b_1}(x)+v_2(x)y_{b_1}(x)$$ this gives the result above.